# Template.myTemplate.rendered not rendered until after a page refresh

Tags: javascript, meteor

To avoid the error "Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of undefined" I check that Meteor.user() has returned an object:

```
Template.create.isActive = function () {
  var user = Meteor.user();
  return user && user.profle.isActive;
};
```

When I implement this change it solves the error message, but creates a new problem... the 'Template.create.rendered = function ()' no longer gets rendered. It is only rendered after a refresh of the page. Any idea how to resolve this?

### Update

Code in Template.myTemplate.rendered...

```
Template.create.rendered = function() {
  if (!this._rendered) {
    this._rendered = true;

    // Form validation
    $("#create").bootstrapValidator({
      feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
      },
      /* submitButtons: '#fakeSubmit', Trick validator until https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator/pull/244 is fixed */
      submitHandler: function(validator, form, submitButton) {
        var $form = $('#buildingCreate');

        var building = {
          company: $form.find('[name=company]').val(),
          address: $form.find('[name=address]').val(),
          floor: $form.find('[name=floor]').val()
        };

        Meteor.call('ensureBuilding', building.company, building.address, building.floor);

        Router.go('create');
      },
      fields: {
        company: {
          trigger: 'blur',
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please provide the company name'
            }
          }
        },
        address: {
          trigger: 'blur',
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please provide the company address'
                }
              }
            },
            floor: {
              trigger: 'blur',
              validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                  message: 'Please provide the floor'
                }
              }
            }
          }
        })
      }
    };
```

Comment: Can you show what is in the rendered function?

Comment: Neil - updated the post with what is in the rendered function...

Comment: When are you expecting `rendered` to be called?

Comment: At the very beginning? In the html file: <template name="create"> and then I run the handlebar {{#if isActive}} .. The issue is it's not re-running the render until the screen is refreshed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [rendered](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_rendered) docs:

> This callback is called once when an instance of Template.myTemplate is rendered into DOM nodes and put into the document for the first time.

If `#create` is inside of an `{{#if}}` block that is false when the template renders, validation will not get initialized.

**Change**

```
<template name="parent">
  {{> create}}
</template>

<template name="create">
  {{#if isActive}}
    <div id="create"> ... </div>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

**to**

```
<template name="parent">
  {{#if isActive}}
    {{> create}}
  {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="create">
  <div id="create"> ... </div>
</template>
```

This way, `#create` is sure to be in the DOM when `rendered` is called. Also, given that rendered is only called once, you shouldn't need `if (!this._rendered) ...`.